# Watson unity android bad recognition

Tags: android

Guys I'm using Unity and Watson to make and vr app that accepts voice commands. I'm using the `ExampleStreaming.cs` provided with the asset but the recognition is terrible. I change the language model to Portuguese on the code. I'm using Samsung galaxy s7 on gear vr with the mic plugged in. I guess the app is using the cellphone mic and not the plugged one. Any help here.

Here's the code

```
private int _recordingRoutine = 0;
private string _microphoneID = null;
private AudioClip _recording = null;
private int _recordingBufferSize = 1;
private int _recordingHZ = 22050;

private SpeechToText _service;

public GolemController GolemControllerObj;

void Start()
{
    LogSystem.InstallDefaultReactors();
    Runnable.Run(CreateService());
}

private IEnumerator CreateService()
{
    //  Create credential and instantiate service
    Credentials credentials = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_password))
    {
        //  Authenticate using username and password
        credentials = new Credentials(_username, _password, _serviceUrl);
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_iamApikey))
    {
        //  Authenticate using iamApikey
        TokenOptions tokenOptions = new TokenOptions()
        {
            IamApiKey = _iamApikey,
            IamUrl = _iamUrl
        };

        credentials = new Credentials(tokenOptions, _serviceUrl);

        //  Wait for tokendata
        while (!credentials.HasIamTokenData())
            yield return null;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new WatsonException("Please provide either username and password or IAM apikey to authenticate the service.");
    }

    _service = new SpeechToText(credentials);
    _service.StreamMultipart = true;
    _service.RecognizeModel="pt-BR_BroadbandModel";

    Active = true;
    StartRecording();
}

public bool Active
{
    get { return _service.IsListening; }
    set
    {
        if (value && !_service.IsListening)
        {
            _service.DetectSilence = true;
            _service.EnableWordConfidence = true;
            _service.EnableTimestamps = true;
            _service.SilenceThreshold = 0.01f;
            _service.MaxAlternatives = 0;
            _service.EnableInterimResults = true;
            _service.OnError = OnError;
            _service.InactivityTimeout = -1;
            _service.ProfanityFilter = false;
            _service.SmartFormatting = true;
            _service.SpeakerLabels = false;
            _service.WordAlternativesThreshold = null;
            _service.StartListening(OnRecognize, OnRecognizeSpeaker);
        }
        else if (!value && _service.IsListening)
        {
            _service.StopListening();
        }
    }
}

private void StartRecording()
{
    if (_recordingRoutine == 0)
    {
        UnityObjectUtil.StartDestroyQueue();
        _recordingRoutine = Runnable.Run(RecordingHandler());
    }
}

private void StopRecording()
{
    if (_recordingRoutine != 0)
    {
        Microphone.End(_microphoneID);
        Runnable.Stop(_recordingRoutine);
        _recordingRoutine = 0;
    }
}

private void OnError(string error)
{
    Active = false;

    Log.Debug("ExampleStreaming.OnError()", "Error! {0}", error);
}

private IEnumerator RecordingHandler()
{
    Log.Debug("ExampleStreaming.RecordingHandler()", "devices: {0}", Microphone.devices);
    _recording = Microphone.Start(_microphoneID, true, _recordingBufferSize, _recordingHZ);
    yield return null;      // let _recordingRoutine get set..

    if (_recording == null)
    {
        StopRecording();
        yield break;
    }

    bool bFirstBlock = true;
    int midPoint = _recording.samples / 2;
    float[] samples = null;

    while (_recordingRoutine != 0 && _recording != null)
    {
        int writePos = Microphone.GetPosition(_microphoneID);
        if (writePos > _recording.samples || !Microphone.IsRecording(_microphoneID))
        {
            Log.Error("ExampleStreaming.RecordingHandler()", "Microphone disconnected.");

            StopRecording();
            yield break;
        }

        if ((bFirstBlock && writePos >= midPoint)
          || (!bFirstBlock && writePos < midPoint))
        {
            // front block is recorded, make a RecordClip and pass it onto our callback.
            samples = new float[midPoint];
            _recording.GetData(samples, bFirstBlock ? 0 : midPoint);

            AudioData record = new AudioData();
            record.MaxLevel = Mathf.Max(Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Min(samples)), Mathf.Max(samples));
            record.Clip = AudioClip.Create("Recording", midPoint, _recording.channels, _recordingHZ, false);
            record.Clip.SetData(samples, 0);

            _service.OnListen(record);

            bFirstBlock = !bFirstBlock;
        }
        else
        {
            // calculate the number of samples remaining until we ready for a block of audio, 
            // and wait that amount of time it will take to record.
            int remaining = bFirstBlock ? (midPoint - writePos) : (_recording.samples - writePos);
            float timeRemaining = (float)remaining / (float)_recordingHZ;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeRemaining);
        }

    }

    yield break;
}

private void OnRecognize(SpeechRecognitionEvent result, Dictionary<string, object> customData)
{
    if (result != null && result.results.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (var res in result.results)
        {
            foreach (var alt in res.alternatives)
            {
                string text = string.Format("{0} ({1}, {2:0.00})\n", alt.transcript, res.final ? "Final" : "Interim", alt.confidence);
                Log.Debug("ExampleStreaming.OnRecognize()", text);
                ResultsField.text = text;
                if(res.final == true)
                    {
                     GolemControllerObj.GolemActions(alt.transcript);
                    }
            }

            if (res.keywords_result != null && res.keywords_result.keyword != null)
            {
                foreach (var keyword in res.keywords_result.keyword)
                {
                    Log.Debug("ExampleStreaming.OnRecognize()", "keyword: {0}, confidence: {1}, start time: {2}, end time: {3}", keyword.normalized_text, keyword.confidence, keyword.start_time, keyword.end_time);
                }
            }

            if (res.word_alternatives != null)
            {
                foreach (var wordAlternative in res.word_alternatives)
                {
                    Log.Debug("ExampleStreaming.OnRecognize()", "Word alternatives found. Start time: {0} | EndTime: {1}", wordAlternative.start_time, wordAlternative.end_time);
                    foreach(var alternative in wordAlternative.alternatives)
                        Log.Debug("ExampleStreaming.OnRecognize()", "\t word: {0} | confidence: {1}", alternative.word, alternative.confidence);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void OnRecognizeSpeaker(SpeakerRecognitionEvent result, Dictionary<string, object> customData)
{
    if (result != null)
    {
        foreach (SpeakerLabelsResult labelResult in result.speaker_labels)
        {
            Log.Debug("ExampleStreaming.OnRecognize()", string.Format("speaker result: {0} | confidence: {3} | from: {1} | to: {2}", labelResult.speaker, labelResult.from, labelResult.to, labelResult.confidence));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the microphone *actually* recognized by the Android device? I.e. have you checked that recording a voice memo or video uses the microphone from the VR gear?

Comment: If the microphone is the issue, you can find the microphone using `Microphone.devices` and explicitly set the `_microphoneID` to the correct microphone.